# Creating New Google Drive Document From Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am trying to add the functionality to create a new Google Drive document (presentation, spreadsheet, etc.) to my app. To do this, I initially wanted to just use URL intents, but it seems that one cannot create a new Google Drive document through the Android browser. My next idea is to somehow integrate with the Google Drive app. Is there anyway to call/open the Google Drive app from my app (for example, with intents)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Drive API to upload a file to Drive and have it automatically converted to the corresponding Google format. For instance, you can upload a text file and have it converted to a Google Docs.

The [Android quickstart for Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) shows how to upload a photo, it should be easy to change the code to upload a different file instead and add the `?convert=true` parameter:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: Hey Claudio, I've looked for some time now, but I can't seem to find where exactly that parameter is supposed to be set. Can you help me out?

Comment: I should actually point out that I just realized that it is possible to create a Document and a Spreadsheet via the Android browser based Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Claudio, the change is minimal when you take a deep look at the API [JavaDoc](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/index.html).

Instead of using

```
File insertedFile = service.files().insert(newFile, content).execute();
```

Use this:

```
Insert fileRequest = service.files().insert(newFile, content);
fileRequest.setConvert(true);
File insertedFile = fileRequest.execute();
```

The conversion table can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open?hl=en

Had and hard time finding this info but now it's all clear.